# Custom property inside Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have something like the following in a WebAPI controller:

```
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get()
{
    var products = from p in db.Products
        select new ProductDTO()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Created = p.Created,
            Title = p.Title,
            CustomValue = ? (if Id=1 or 2, then CustomValue = 1, if Id=3, then CustomValue = 2 etc)
        };

    return products.AsQueryable();
}
```

I want to return a CustomValue based on the value of another property. In this example, the Id. So if the id is 1 or 2, CustomValue should return 1, if Id is 3, CustomValue should be 2 and so on.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about web api or controller,

```
public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get()
{
    var products = from p in db.Products
        select new ProductDTO()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Created = p.Created,
            Title = p.Title,
            CustomValue = p.Id == 1 || p.Id == 2 ? 1 : p.Id == 3 ? 2 :0;
        };

    return products.AsQueryable();
}
```